# Installing setuptools prior to installing python dependencies on Mac

Tags: python, macos, setuptools

I need to install a few python dependencies. To do so with 'easy install', I want to install setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg (md5) on my mac. I've downloaded the egg file from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11. Then I tried to install via terminal:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

But I get an error message: "can't create or remove files in install directory"
(see here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vblZhYnV3TjZwbDA/edit?usp=sharing). Should I try another directory to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command attempts to install files into system directories. You must execute the command as root or with sudo:

```
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

You can see this error with the:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Edit:

If you don't have permissions, you can try installing into your user's Library folder, or look at [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). (See the part about using locally from source.)